# Custom module access denied

Tags: 8, routes

I just have followed two tutorials on Youtube, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79zYcIoheCc&t=43s and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAP9clnOf9E&t=8s.

The result was a "You are not authorized to access this page." error.

In the routing file, I have made the correct indentation for both modules.

```
my_module.routing:
  path: '/admin/structure/my_module'
  defaults:
    _title: 'My module'
    _content: '\Drupal\my_module\MyModuleController::test'
  requirements:
    _permisions: 'access administracion pages'

hello_world:
    path: '/hello/world'
    defaults:
        _controller: 'Drupal\hello_world\Controller\HelloWorldController::hello'
    requirements:
        _permisions: 'access content'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in one of the permissions. It should be “administration”. Permissions itself is also spelled incorrectly.

Please refer to the official docs for creating routes and links. YouTube videos may be out of date.

Comment: Also the indentation seems wrong, if part of the file is using two spaces, and the other four spaces.